# How can I make value of a record to be title of field on the mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

My query like this :

```
SELECT a.number, a.description, b.attribute_code, b.attribute_value 
FROM items a 
JOIN attr_maps b ON b.number = a.number WHERE a.number = AB123
```

If the query executed, the result like this :

[image]

I want to make the result like this :

[image]

How can I do it?

Comment: [MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT i.number, i.description,
       MAX(CASE WHEN am.attribute_code = 'brand' then am.attribute_value END) as brand,
       MAX(CASE WHEN am.attribute_code = 'model' then am.attribute_value END) as model,
       MAX(CASE WHEN am.attribute_code = 'category' then am.attribute_value END) as category,
       MAX(CASE WHEN am.attribute_code = 'subcategory' then am.attribute_value END) as subcategory
FROM items i JOIN
     attr_maps am
     ON am.number = i.number
WHERE i.number = AB123
GROUP BY i.number, i.description
```

Comment: Great. It works. Thanks a lot

Comment: How can I filter by brand or model or category or subcategory. I try to add `WHERE brand = 'honda'`, there exist error like this :  `#1054 - Unknown column 'brand' in 'where clause'`

Comment: @SuccessMan . . . You can use a `having` clause . . . `HAVING brand = 'honda'`.